# background behind dialog in android

Tags: android, background, dialog

I want to use whole black background behind the dialog, but when I change background to #FF000000 is see black color only on the middle of the screen (it should fill whole screen).

[image]

Here are my styles for a dialg:

```
<style name="dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using either 'match_parent' or 'fill_parent' for the layout_width and layout_height attributes of the layout file?  If you use wrap_content it won't extend your view to the edges of the screen

Comment: I don't have custom layout for the dialog I just want to change styles, to show dialog I just execute Dialog.show(...)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting android:backgroundDimEnabled to true and create a new item for dimAmount with a value of 1.

Otherwise, add the following to your code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( );
params.copyFrom( m_dialog.getWindow( ).getAttributes( ) );
params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
m_dialog.getWindow( ).setAttributes( params );
```